# Why am I getting 5V at the hex inverter output?

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, digital-logic

Why am I getting 5V at point A?
The microcontroller IO is 3.3V.

[image]

Comment: (*point A* left bottom at the net including pin 12/signal 6Y - signal flow is right-to-left)

Comment: What are "5V switches"?  It seems to me you have just normal switches with pull-up resistors. Why can't you just "pull up" to +3.3V (instead of +5V), and power the 74HC14 from +3.3V too? And if that's possible, why do you even need the 74HC14 in the middle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An open drain/collector inverter will not drive its outputs high and the pullups voltage will set Vout.

An inverter that is not open-drain will drive its outputs to near its V+ supply voltage - in this case = 5V.

The [MC74ACT05DR2 open drain inverter](https://www.digikey.co.nz/en/products/detail/onsemi/MC74ACT05DR2/11529178) will do what you want.

The 74AC05 also will. [Datasheet for both here](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mc74ac05-d.pdf)
It's intended to emulate an LS type open drain part.

An alternative is to use a 3V3 supply inverter and  5v to 3V3 input divider.

---

Q:  Please specify the inverter type that you are using.

A:  That's a possible but not certain solution. It will work IF the inverters are tolerant of 5V input.

As I said, ideally you need either open drain inverters or - not mentioned, inverters designed for level shifting.

Comment: Thanks, you mean to say i should connect IC VCC pin to 3.3V right?

Comment: That's a possible but not certain solution. It will work IF the inverters are tolerant of 5V input.|| As I said, ideally you need either open drain inverters or - not mentioned, inverters designed for level shifting.

Comment: @greybeard Thanks. Yes :-( . Corrected in both cases.